# Asyncronous set method in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When registering a new user using Mongoose & MongoDB i would like to fetch values from another collection before saving the user instance. Currently I use the following solution, but this causes the user to get saved twice... Even worse, if the user does not pass the first validation the `save()` inside the set method is called anyway... usually resulting in an uncaught exception.

My current code works the following way:

```
UserSchema.path('address.postCode').set(function(newVal, cb) {
    var that = this;

    this.model('PostCode').findOne({ postCode: newVal }, function(err, postCode) {
        if(postCode) {
            that.longitude = postCode.longitude;
            that.latitude = postCode.latitude;
        } else {
            that.longitude = undefined;
            that.latitude = undefined;
        }
        that.save();
    });
    return newVal;
});
```

Anyone know  a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`SchemaType#set`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-set) function expects a synchronous return. You have an asynchronous call inside this function and therefore the `return` will be called before `PostCode` returns its results.

Also, you shouldn't be calling `save()` inside the setter, since it will be saved anyway.

Since you want to fetch data from another model, you should use a pre middleware. For example:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', true, function (next, done) {
    var that = this;

    if(this.isNew || this.isModified('address.postCode')) {
        this.model('PostCode').findOne({ postCode: that.address.postCode }, function(err, postCode) {
            if(postCode) {
                that.longitude = postCode.longitude;
                that.latitude = postCode.latitude;
            } else {
                that.longitude = undefined;
                that.latitude = undefined;
            }
            done();
        });
    }

    next();
});
```

The second parameter passed to `pre` (`true`) is what defines this is an asynchronous middleware.

For more information in middlewares, check the [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

Comment: Is there anyway to do this on updates as well but ONLY when the user changes postCode?